# Restrict access to bluemix app

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have node.js bluemix app. I don't want the bluemix app url to be publicly available. Is there a way to restrict access to bluemix app from certain IP addresses only ? 
I know I can build authentication in the app itself but I am trying to avoid that. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The Bluemix CloudFoundry platform can not restrict routes to a certain IP address. Like you said, all authentication has to be part of the application logic.

Check out the express-ipfilter npm module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ipfilter

Whitelisting certain IP addresses, while denying all other IPs:

```
// Init dependencies 
var express = require('express')
    , ipfilter = require('express-ipfilter')
    , app = express.createServer()
    ;

// Whitelist the following IPs 
var ips = ['127.0.0.1'];

// Create the server 
app.use(ipfilter(ips, {mode: 'allow'}));
app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ram mentioned you cannot restrict routes to a certain IP for a Bluemix app, but there is an alternative using IBM Containers.

You can deploy your node.js in an IBM Container (docker) and use the IBM VPN service to restrict access to your container instance to your company's VPN.

You can find more details on this service here:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/vpn/index.html